# Cannot find Windows Installer XML node after WIX toolset installation in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix, nuget

I cannot find the Windows Installer XML node after installing Wix toolset using the nuget.org packet manager. I am running VS 2013, and the version of Wix Windows Installer XML Toolset available is 3.9.2. What can I do to have this node appear after I right click my Solution and say add new project? On attempting to install the version from  the website. It gives me an error "Failed, try again?" My solution already has a setup project created with Visual Studio Installer from an earlier version of VS however, it is not compatible with VS2013 and hence the switch to Wix.

Comment: I am having the same issue but with VS 2015, same version of Wix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem in particular was caused by the antivirus blocking the Wix Toolset Installer(downloaded from the website) from writing to the registry. I was using McAfee so I disabled access protection and the on access scanner and it worked. I found this out by navigating to my temporary folder to find the WIX toolset install log. I did this by typing %TMP% in the search textbox (windows 7). I then found the entries

> [19D8:1428][2015-07-29T19:03:09]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to
>   write run key value. [19D8:1428][2015-07-29T19:03:09]e000: Error
>   0x80070005: Failed to update resume mode.
>   [19D8:1428][2015-07-29T19:03:09]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to
>   begin registration session. [1FA8:0C7C][2015-07-29T19:03:09]e000:
>   Error 0x80070005: Failed to begin registration session in per-machine
>   process. [1FA8:0C7C][2015-07-29T19:03:09]e000: Error 0x80070005:
>   Failed to register bundle.

I still can't use the wix toolset installer from the nuget package manager, but since the downloaded version of the website has now been installed successfully, I can recommend using it and following the above procedure if you have the same problem.